# UIActionSheet always on top of view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

I have implemented a Pin-Lock viewController  such that every time app becomes active, the Pass-Lock view is shown.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{

    //--- showing Pass-Lock View
}
```

But,while resigningActive,if any `UIActionSheet` was displaying(Any where in the App). On resuming the App the Pass-Lock view is shown along with the `UIActionSheet`.

Till now I have implemented one "`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`", but this is particular to one view. So I have to implement is all over the app.

Can any one suggest better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use notifications for this. because, We have already some delegate methods in application delegate class. These delegates will call according to the application status. This will work for all over the app. So that, you can continue with those delegates.